# flex, flash with php

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex

I am a newbie to flex/flash platform. At present, I am working on a project which is similarly looks like this site http://www.newsweek.com/2010/08/15/interactive-infographic-of-the-worlds-best-countries.html (i.e. which includes FORM, GRAPH, DATAGRID etc.. components). In this site, too many 3D effects applied on graph, accordion, list, label.. components. I need to apply same kind of effects in my project. Anybody is there to guide and help me on the following items,

1. Which is the best platform do I need use (which includes the 3D effects also)? FLASH with PHP or FLEX with PHP.
2. Sample kick start material with the source code (for better understanding).
3. Which is the best platform tp achieve the 3D effects and custom styling? FLASH or FLEX.

Answer (score 3):

there is not difference between Flash and Flex ( pointing probably to Flash Professional CS, and Flash Builder 4.5 ( flex ) )

They both is compiling up to Flash executable file.

Flash Professional CS ( CS5.5 ) is usually more the creative way of developing things, while Flash Builder ( 4.5 ) ( Flex ) is providing more control over the code.

Whatever you do, you can accomplish the same results, with both IDE's.
They both using the same API exporting from the Flash platform.

check my answer here : [Is Flash or Flex better to build a user interactive ordering "wizard" website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398079/should-i-use-flash-or-flex-to-build-an-interactive-ordering-wizard-website/6401824#6401824)

it could prove useful for you as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will surely follow your steps. But at the same time, can you please guide me like where I can find out 3rd party graph and accordion components for jazzy look.

Comment: there is accordion and graphs inside Flash Builder ( flex ), else u can get some from http://activeden.net/ about flash components.

Comment: thanks once more. In this [activeden.net](http://activeden.net/) site, all the 3rd party components are not for free?

Comment: there is free ofc, but i am suggesting you looking a bit into professional created components, learned the structure, and then better start building whatever you wish. Especially the Flash Professional is not so restrictive as Flex, so - there will have full power without limitations. Anyway in your very specific case - this will be the 1st step, and probably you will jump soon into Flex's waters as i had to before less than a month.